# How to pass thread id through pending intent

Tags: android

How to pass thread id through pending intent to open exact message conversation, like when we get a message with click notification and see the conversation

```
PendingIntent nPendingInten = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConvActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_ID_EXTRA, threadId);
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_NAME_EXTRA,listItem.getContactName());
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_IMAGE_EXTRA, uri);
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_NUM_EXTRA,listItem.getAddress());
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: so what do you have problems with?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing another intent to your pending intent - pay attention.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConvActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_ID_EXTRA, threadId);
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_NAME_EXTRA,listItem.getContactName());
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_IMAGE_EXTRA, uri);
                    intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_NUM_EXTRA,listItem.getAddress());
    PendingIntent nPendingInten = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
PendingIntent nPendingInten = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConvActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_ID_EXTRA,    

threadId.longvalue);// change here
                intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_NAME_EXTRA,listItem.getContactName());
                intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_IMAGE_EXTRA, uri);
                intent.putExtra(ConvActivity.THREAD_NUM_EXTRA,listItem.getAddress());
```